# Using Object.keys() inside an EJS page

Tags: javascript, ejs

I'm currently using the following code that works inside an EJS page:

```
<% for (let i = 0; i < content.length; i++) { %>
  <% console.log(content[i].title) %>
<% } %>
```

I want to know why the following, using Object.keys(), only logs the key indexes and what I need to change to correct it, keeping Object.keys()

```
<% for (let i = 0; i < content.length; i++) { %>
  <% console.log(Object.keys(content)[i]) %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: `Object.keys()` on an array will return the indexes of the array

Comment: Because that is what Object.keys does just gets an array of the object's keys. Are you trying to log the values of `content[i]` keys without knowing their names? If so you would need to loop over `Object.keys(content[i])` and use each as a key to `content[i]`, eg `k=Object.keys(content[i]); content[i][ k[0] ]`

Comment: I see my mistake now. My 'content' isn't an object, but an array of objects. Thanks